# Template and map in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I have the following code in c++, involving templates :

```
 #include <assert.h>
 #include <map>
 #include <limits>

 template<class K, class V> class interval_mapping {
 private:   
    std::map<K,V> aMap;

 public:
    interval_mapping( V const& val) {
        aMap.insert(
            aMap.begin(),
            std::make_pair(std::numeric_limits<K>::min(),val)
        );
    }

  void assign( K const& keyBegin, K const& keyEnd, const V& val ) {}

   V const& operator[]( K const& key ) const {
         return ( --m_map.upper_bound(key) )->second;
   }
 };

int main()
{
     interval_mapping<int, char> myMap;
}
```

I get the error:

> no default constructor exists for class "interval_mapping"

Comment: exactly what the error say: `interval_mapping<int, char> myMap;` this line declare a variable `myMap` and call the default constructor of the class and the constructor is not present.

Comment: If you don't know what a *default constructor* is - it is a constructor that has no parameters.  Knowing that is foundational, and would have easily helped you see the error.  So you might want to bite the bullet and review some basics before defining your own templated classes!  :-/  In any case, welcome to StackOverflow...and note that putting signatures in questions or saying "Thanks in advance" is considered [to just take up space](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/211160); less is more!

Comment: To all: thank you very much; the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error should be pretty self-explanatory: you're constructing an `interval_mapping` object without passing any arguments, so the class needs a default constructor. Default constructors are only auto-generated by the compiler if you don't provide any other constructors yourself.

You don't need the default constructor to do anything special, so you can just add

```
interval_mapping() {}
```

to the class, or

```
interval_mapping() = default;
```

if your compiler supports C++11.

If you genuinely didn't want the class to have a default constructor, you need to give an argument in the line in `main()` where you create the object.

Comment: What's the downvote for? I can't see anything wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, there's no default constructor, since you've declared your own constructor.

Either use that constructor

```
interval_mapping<int, char> myMap(some_char_value);
```

or add a default constructor; you probably want it to be empty initially:

```
interval_mapping() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare a constructor for `interval_mapping` that takes a `V const& val`. This is the only constructor declared for `interval_mapping` and no default constructors are provided since you have implemented your own.

Then when you try to instantiate an `interval_mapping<int, char>` you fail to provide the `V const& val` needed by the constructor (in this case that would be a `char` it seems). And since there is no available constructor that takes no parameters you see this error.